# How to prevent "EOFError: Ran out of input" when saving & loading model's parameters?

Tags: python, pytorch, google-colaboratory

I'm using Google Colab to run my PyTorch model. I'm saving my model's `state dict` using [this](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/saving_loading_models.html) method every 100 epochs, and I believe the reason I'm getting this error is that Google Colab is sometimes shutting down the session in the middle of the automatic `state dict` saving. That is, because I only get the error **sometimes** after the shutdown when I try to reload the `state dict` file.

The full error:

```
EOFError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-01fb93bcf161> in <module>()
----> 1 get_ipython().run_cell_magic(...)
4 frames
<decorator-gen-53> in time(self, line, cell, local_ns)

<timed exec> in <module>()

<timed exec> in train(self, n_epochs)

<timed exec> in load(self)

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/serialization.py in _legacy_load(f, map_location, pickle_module, **pickle_load_args)
    760             "functionality.")
    761 
--> 762     magic_number = pickle_module.load(f, **pickle_load_args)
    763     if magic_number != MAGIC_NUMBER:
    764         raise RuntimeError("Invalid magic number; corrupt file?")

EOFError: Ran out of input
```

Comment: Pytorch has specific pickle-based functions for saving and loading pytorch objects which are recommended. You may want to try using these instead to start.


`torch.save(model.state_dict(), "save_file.pt")`

Comment: I am using that... I specifically added the link to that

Comment: You should include your code then and other details that might help someone solve your problem. Details are pretty sparse here

Comment: One possibility is, if your model is very large, you may be running out of memory in your Colab instance while saving. I doubt that unless your model is quite big though

Comment: Yea I think it's running out of RAM. I've been training it for about 6 hours now and the RAM bar is almost full so I expect it to crush. So far what I came up with is just to have 2 alternating files that I'm saving my model to. So after 100 epochs it will save to file 1, and after 100 more it will save to file 2, and alternate. This way when it crushes I'll have the other file to load to. I'm hoping that there might be another, neater solution, but I'll check if this works once it crushes. Appreciate the help!

Comment: How big is the save file itself? Saving should store the model in disk space, not RAM. I'd recommend trying to clean up unused variables to save on RAM, and I think you can also request an instance with more RAM if necessary.

Comment: Also, a quick workaround is to save each epoch (or periodically) a new instance of the model (provided it's not too huge to store). During training I always save:
`model_epoch1.pt`, `model_epoch2.pt`, `model_epoch3.pt`, etc. Then when you restart, you can check for the largest epoch that was successfully saved and load from there